What are feasible descent directions in an intuitive sense?
Right now I am taking a course on nonlinear optimization. Currently we are dealing with restricted optimization and the tangent cone.
Let $X$ be the set of feasible solutions for a nonlinear optimization problem.
So far I understand that the tangent cone kind of tries to caputure all directions which COULD be descent directions still keeping us inside of $X$. This seems logical to me since why should I care about descent directions which would make me leave $X$.
But there is a thing which intuitively doesn't make so much sense to me right now. Let $$X = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \; | \;x^2 + y^2 = 1\}.$$
According to the definition of a tangent cone in a point $x\in X$, this tangent cone contains the tangent at the point $x$.
But no matter how small of a step size(but not zero of course) you take in such a direction, $x+td, t>0$ will always be outside of $X$ and so I don't really get why it is reasonable to count such directions as "feasible" in this sense.
